# Cannot read files from a directory - android

Tags: android, audio, directory, media-player, directory-permissions

I have a directory /sdcard/audio in the project. This directory contains some audio (wav) files.
Here is what I am trying to do:
1. Read from the directory.
2. Play the wav files.

The code I have written for accessing the directory is as follows:

```
String path_to_media = "/sdcard/audio/";
File dirEffectFiles = new File(path_to_media);   //gets a handle to the directory of effect files.
Log.v(this.toString(), "Getting into path = " + path_to_media);
Log.v(this.toString(), "Some details about the directory: path = " + dirEffectFiles.getPath()
                + " Can read: " + dirEffectFiles.canRead() + " list:" + dirEffectFiles.list()
                + " absolute path:" + dirEffectFiles.getAbsolutePath() + " is absolute:" + dirEffectFiles.isAbsolute());
```

The output I get for the above is:

> 01-13 16:23:34.941: Some details about
>   the directory: path = /sdcard/audio
>   Can read: false list:null absolute
>   path:/sdcard/audio is absolute:true

I have the following questions:
1. How can I make the above folder readable? By setting `dirEffectFiles.setReadable(true)`?
2. Also, please note that `path_to_media` above is /sdcard/audio/. When it is printed, the last "/" disappears. Is that a normal effect of some internal parsing or should I be worried about that??

Any help is most welcome,
Thanks,
Sriram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/sdcard/audio referred to above was a directory made in the project directory. This approach is wrong. The directory for emulating the sdcard must be created using adb (in command prompt (windows))like so:

1. `adb shell mkdir /sdcard/audio`   - this will create the audio/ sub-directory in sdcard/
2. `adb push "complete path of file name to be pushed" /sdcard/audio/file-name`
3. This procedure is repeated for the other wavefiles.

That's it. You should be able to read files from the mounted /sdcard directory.
@thoredge: thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the right permission to AndroidManifest.xml?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Also, it is wise to use a the environment method to get the correct SD-card path:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

Also, what do you get from:

```
dirEffectFiles.exists()
```

Comment: I added the permissions line to the manifest. When I print the details from the getExternalStorageDirectory(), I get /mnt/sdcard to be the external storage directory. Also, the exists() function returns false. I think I may have to change the path_to_media. Let me get back to you.

Comment: it seems changing path_to_media to /mnt/sdcard/audio does not work. But does /mnt/sdcard refer to the folder /sdcard within the project directory or does it refer to the image of the sdcard made with mksdcard?

Comment: It should refer to where the sd-card is mounted; if you have an sd-card inserted. 

Does the audio directory exist on the sd-card already? Is it all lower case (I'm not sure whether its case-less or not)?

Comment: I do not have an sdcard inserted. I created a folder in the project directory called sdcard and a sub-folder called audio/. I put my wav files in audio/. Every directory name is lower-case. My API is 2.3 level 9. And referring to my previous comment, using exists() on File descriptor returned from /mnt/sdcard also returns false.

Comment: Storage on Android is very managed (see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html). Basically you can use external (sd-card) or internal (private area for each application). To reach internal area you must use Context.getFilesDir() (see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)